# Define($DB_DBNAME) accessibility through out

Tags: php

I have `Define($DB_DBNAME)` in the config.php located in the root. There is a header file that requires this config.php.

Does it have to be included as `include('config.php')` or does it have to be defined as a global variable and is accessible everywhere?

Below is the config.php file

```
define('DB_NAME', '');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '');
```

**OR should I use this**

```
$hostname_writehost = "";
$database_writehost = "";
$username_writehost = "";
$password_writehost = "";
$writehost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_writehost, $username_writehost, $password_writehost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: You don't need to define it as global if it's already in the global scope... without showing your code it's hard to tell (if you're using namespaces for example)..

Comment: Your question is actually about using constants (define) or variables, if you want to ensure those details are not changed use constants (your first example), otherwise use variables.

Comment: Coming back to the Q, can I call these without setting up the path for the config.php in the themes?

Comment: It depends on how the themes are launched, why don't you try it?

Comment: Just tried it after include('config.php') from the index.php
Option 1: I did an echo DB_HOST; it did not echo.
Option 2: It did echo hostname_writehost;

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are your themes being loaded?

Comment: @X10nD when you define a constant on your config.php and include it in  the very beginning of each next file you wont need to think about global scope just use `echo DB_NAME;` you'll see your configurations printing out.

Comment: @Martin did not uderstand, as to how my themes are being loaded.

Comment: @Ghostology It does not print out.  Now if I were to Global the variables then would I have to include it in every file?

Comment: Think of this:
config.php - YOUR CONSTANTS
header.php - YOUR DEFAULT HEADER (include config.php here)
and it has to work you may miss anything else. Show us your code how you do link files.

Comment: loading it as include('config.php').  I want to avoid this as I do not want theme designers involving with this.

Comment: Its based on your structure and programming design. If you work with MVC you sure wont have these issues. Maybe its time to move to OOP.

Comment: @Ghostology there is no MVC / Frameworks its all raw coding.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include your configuration once at the entry point (typically your `index.php`) and it will be accessible everywhere.

To answer your comment more clearly (automatically including the global variables, or config is this case) you can use a .htaccess file, or modify your php-fpm config depending on your setup to automatically prepend it upon each request like so:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/config.php
```

Comment: Can I avoid doing that, since this folder is the themes and I am letting customization and letting everyone setup new themes.

Comment: @Matrin So I have to modify the php-fpm config file to avoid other designers setting up the path to the config?

Comment: @X10nD it depends if you can control the inclusion of the themes and include the config before the theme is loaded

Comment: If the theme is uplaoded via ftp then, how do I control it?  Just asking

Comment: Not uploaded, loaded by PHP. Do you `include 'theme.php'`?

Comment: @Matrin include 'theme.php' to load the config.php?

Comment: @X10nD no, we're trying to figure out (including in the main comments) how your designers themes are being used, so we know what scope they're in

Comment: Now I am totally confused.

Comment: Show us more code :) specifically around: "I am letting customization and letting everyone setup new themes"